# Dynamic changing picture in ActionScript 3 without flickering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I want to have a image in my Flash file which can be changed from another program.

In ActionScript 2 I used a  `Loader`, set the `contentPath` and made a `Motiontween` in the Timeline this worked very well.

But now in Actionscript 3 I do the same, I use the `UILoader`, I set the `source` and create a `Motiontween` but now  the image disappears for a short time, everytime the Tween starts over again.

Is there a way to do this properly?

My code right now:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

var text:String;
var imagePath:String;

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:/Flash/paths.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{       
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    text = myXML.text;
    imagePath = myXML.path;

    TextContainer.text = team1name;
    imageContainer.source = team2logoPath;

    trace("trace");    
}
```

The text isn't flickering but the image is, so I don't think the XML Loader is the reason that it works with and not with AS3.

Even if I only change the source of the image every time, the image gets invisible for a short time:

```
imageContainer.source = "C:/images/no_image.png";
```

Comment: sounds like your tween is off POST CODE

Comment: I added my code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the flickering you are getting is the load time it takes to download the image or in the 3sample you provided loading the image from disk. If you want to avoid this you need to preload the image in one way or another.
You find an open source preload easy.
What I would do is create an array of image containers and just remove current element from stage and then add the next one in the array when you want to change images.
With this method you will assign the source to the item and it will download it even if it is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there an Event.COMPLETE event for the UILoader which is fired when content is loaded, then in the event handler start the tweening.